# JFactory::getApplication()->set security?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

In my custom component I use

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$app->set('some_variable', 'some_value');
$someValue = $app->get('some_variable');
```

in a helper file invoked by the component root file.

I am unsure how secure this is? Is the data stored server side or client side? Does the client have any way of manipulating the variable and changing its value? Like using a developer browser add-on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting it server side and your value is manually set from your code not fetched dynamically then set so it's perfectly secure.